# .Net Parallel.For strange behavior

Tags: .net-4.0

I brute-forced summing of all primes under 2000000. After that, just for fun I tried to parallel my for, but I was a little bit surprised when I saw that `Parallel.For` gives me an **incorrect** sum!

Here's my code : (C#)

```
static class Problem
{
    public static long Solution()
    {
        long sum = 0;
        //Correct result is 142913828922
        //Parallel.For(2, 2000000, i =>
        //                             {
        //                                 if (IsPrime(i)) sum += i;
        //                             });
        for (int i = 2; i < 2000000; i++)
        {
            if (IsPrime(i)) sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    private static bool IsPrime(int value)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= (int)Math.Sqrt(value); i++)
        {
            if (value % i == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I know that brute-force is pretty bad solution here but that is not a question about that. I think I've made some very stupid mistake, but I just can't locate it. So, `for` is calculating correctly, but `Parallel.For` is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parallel.For(): Update variable outside of loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774170/parallel-for-update-variable-outside-of-loop)

Comment: And exact duplicate of [Different summation results with Parallel.ForEach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367293/different-summation-results-with-parallel-foreach/3367311#3367311)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing the variable sum from multiple threads without locking it, so it is possible that the read / write operations become overlapped.

Adding a lock will correct the result (but you will be effectively serializing the computation, losing the benefit you were aiming for).

You should instead calculate a subtotal on each thread and add the sub-totals at the end. See the article [How to: Write a Parallel.For Loop That Has Thread-Local Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703.aspx) on MSDN for more details.

```
long total = 0;

// Use type parameter to make subtotal a long, not an int
Parallel.For<long>(0, nums.Length, () => 0, (j, loop, subtotal) =>
{
    subtotal += nums[j];
    return subtotal;
},
    (x) => Interlocked.Add(ref total, x)
);
```

Comment: But I thought Parallel.For is doing all the job for synchronizing threads and locking variables...

Comment: @tars.roshko: What does being a value type have to do with whether or not you should lock? The two concepts are totally unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all of you for your quick answers
i changed

sum += i;
to
Interlocked.Add(ref sum,i);

and now it works great.

Comment: It will give the correct result but now you've lost the benefit of parallelizing as you are effectively serializing the calculation.