# System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I have a trouble with getting perfect result using Parallel.

What I did

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> listInt = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        listInt.Add(i);

    }
    int cnt = 0;
    Parallel.ForEach(listInt, num =>
        {
            cnt++;
        }
    );
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
    //it should show 10000 but it gives random result
    Response.Write(cnt);
}
```

I was expecting to get 10000 as response but it is giving random result.

What I am doing wrong to get the accurate result.

[Live test is here](http://nazmulweb.com/jsondevsite/job3.aspx).

Thank you so much.

Comment: there are probably a lot of answers on this - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394447/increment-a-count-value-outside-parallel-foreach-scope

Comment: [C# Parallel Programming – Increment variable safely across multiple threads](http://pragmaticpattern.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/c-parallel-programming-increment-variable-safely-across-multiple-threads/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not threadsafe.

You can use something like this:

```
private static readonly object SyncRoot = new object();
```

and

```
lock (SyncRoot)
{
    cnt++;
}
```

Check this dotnetfiddle http://dotnetfiddle.net/D7QoP9

Comment: Put the relevant code bits in your post, so if the fiddle goes away in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not "threadsafe", that is a "Race".

Add a lock around `cnt++` to see the expected result.

Or just use

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref cnt);
```