# Only 1 process is showing activity parallel foreach

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, process

So I am using a Parallel.Foreach because I want to start 4 unique processes that does essentially the same thing. Watermarks a video.

How it should work is that it should open 4 ffmpeg.exe and pass an argument to each window so it watermarks 4 videos at a time.
However.. That's not what is happening, It opens 4 processes but only 1 is active. Not sure if it's trying to use the same one 4 times or what ever it could be but I need help.

When I close the working process, the 3 non working ones are still there until I manually close them down.
Here is a visual representation

[image: pic1]

Here is a second image showing what happends when closing the working one

[image]

Here is the code:

```
public void Watermark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the directory with the mp4 files: ");
        string EntryPath = Console.ReadLine();

        //Console.WriteLine("Please enter the directory with the mp4 files: ");
        //string OutputPath = Console.ReadLine();

        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psi.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
        int i = 0;

        var videos = Directory.EnumerateFiles(EntryPath, "*.mp4");
        Parallel.ForEach(videos, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
            vid =>
            {
                try
                {
                    //Maybe those processes are trying to work on the same file and can't access it?
                    //It's probably better to use the event Exited than WaitForExit
                    psi.Arguments = $"-i {vid} -i watermarker.png -threads 4 -filter_complex \"overlay = 275:350\" C:\\Users\\Developer\\Desktop\\Eh\\Watermarked{i}.mp4";
                    var p = Process.Start(psi);
                    p.WaitForExit();

                    Console.WriteLine($"{vid} is watermarked");
                    i++;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error parsing that file");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                }

            });
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Alll the operations seem to be sharing `psi`..?

Comment: What happens when you try to run four ffmpeg instances from the command line (i.e. four different command prompt windows, or a single one using `&` between each command)? Your question doesn't look like an actual programming question to me. It seems more likely to be a question about how to use ffmpeg.

Comment: @stuartd: without a good [mcve], it's impossible to know for sure. But it seems likely `psi` refers to a `ProcessStartInfo` instance. While sharing that object is likely to be incorrect, it doesn't seem like that would have anything to do with why one ffmpeg process appears to be active while the others are not. If there was a file-sharing violation, I would expect ffmpeg to just quit with an error, rather than sit there doing nothing.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Added the rest of the code, my bad on that part.

Comment: That's not "the rest of the code", nor is it a _minimal_ example. That said, you should try moving the `ProcessStartInfo` object into the `ForEach()` delegate, and use a `ForEach()` overload that provides an index to set the `i` value (e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783359(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of trying to share that variable as well. Even if you got lucky and the code you have worked, it's very wrong.

Comment: Ahh! There was this thing in the back of my head saying, its probably a scope issue, you need a int that increments aswell etc but yeah.. I'll try it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your incremental (`i++`) is wrong so all processes try to output to the same file (Watermarked0.mp4) due to the fact that `i` stays 0 given the current code. You need to use `Interlocked.Increment(ref i)` like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(videos, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
        vid =>
        {
            try
            {
                //Maybe those processes are trying to work on the same file and can't access it?
                //It's probably better to use the event Exited than WaitForExit
                psi.Arguments = $"-i {vid} -i watermarker.png -threads 4 -filter_complex \"overlay = 275:350\" C:\\Users\\Developer\\Desktop\\Eh\\Watermarked{Interlocked.Increment(ref i)}.mp4";
                var p = Process.Start(psi);
                p.WaitForExit();

                Console.WriteLine($"{vid} is watermarked");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Error parsing that file");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }

        });
    Console.ReadLine();
```

I suspect that is the reason why only one process is active. But can't you use a Guid or something as the unique part of the filename to avoid the counter at all as you are not supposed to have shared state in a `Parallel.ForEach`?

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394447/increment-a-count-value-outside-parallel-foreach-scope) Q&A.

Comment: That was the reason! I LOVE learnign new things, that makes so much sense to why it got "locked"!